# Grid walk vs. uniform random weights for bounded grid

Tags: discretization, grid, random-sampling

I want to sample from a bounded space, say $[0,1] \times [0,1] \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

I have read about a so-called grid walk that fixes a starting point $x_0 = (x_{0,1}, x_{0,2})$ and then proceeds via $x_{t+1}= x_t + \epsilon_t$ for MC draws indexed by $t$.

What is the advantage of this scheme relative to sampling like $x_t = (r_{t,1} ,r_{t,2)} $ where $r_{t,i}$ is a uniformly distributed r.v. with support in $[0,1]$ that is independent across $i$ and $t$?

If the grid walk is indeed better, how can I engineer reflecting walls or something similar whenever a random variate $x_t \notin [0,1] \times [0,1] $?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you need your values to be correlated in some way?

Comment: @Richard thank you for your interest. I do not understand: do you mean off-diagonal entries of the cov matrix of the epsilons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every method that seems reasonable leads to an algorithm that is competitive. In your case, if you want to draw uniform random numbers from $[0,1]^2$, you *could* use a method that is based on random walks (where, for example, you deal with the edges of the square by wrapping around periodically), but that is not a competitive algorithm because we have much faster ways of dealing with drawing uniform random numbers.

There *is* a case where that is interesting, though. If you devise a random walk where a particle that reaches the boundary is deleted, and the random walk re-started at the same original point you started all previous random walks, then the probability of drawing a point $\hat x\in [0,1]^2$ is proportional to the value of the first eigenfunction of the Laplace operator on the square. That is, the random walk gives you a way to compute the first eigenfunction of the Laplace operator (which is true on any domain, by the way). Of course, there too one can come up with more efficient ways of computing the eigenfunctions, and you wouldn't do it via the random walk. Rather, one typically does it the other way around: If you want to learn something about random walks with absorbing boundary conditions, you would do that by solving for the first eigenfunction of the Laplace operator using one of the efficient ways of doing so.

Comment: Thank you! So are you saying from a performance point of view, the tuple of uniformly distrib. random numbers is better than a grid walk?

Comment: It is very cheap to create a random number between zero and one. It is quite expensive to run a random walk sufficiently long that each draw from the random walk is statistically independent. So yes, the tuple of numbers is vastly cheaper.

Comment: Thank you very much! Would that mean that MCMC would sometimes be a suboptimal choice for exploring/covering high-dimensional parameter spaces?

Comment: It's all a question of what the comparison is. If you want to draw a number from $[0,1]^d$ with $d=10,000$, then using MCMC is still the wrong algorithm. If you want to draw from a probability distribution $\pi(x)$ on $x\in \Omega \subset R^d$ with $d=10,000$ and $\pi(x) \propto v_1(x)$ where $v_1$ is the lowest eigenfunction of the Laplacian on that domain, then using a random walk is exactly the right algorithm because we cannot compute eigenfunctions on general domains $\Omega$ in high dimensions.